# How to configure output of dpkg -l (dpkg-query)

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have 2 machines, which output different things on `dpkg -l` different manner: 2nd is displaying "Architecture" only in one machine.

How to set output language for `dpkg` and force it to ouptut "Architecture" information?

#### 1

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                       Description
+++-===================================-============================-============
```

#### 2

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                       Architecture Description
+++-==================================-=============================-============-============
```

`dpkg-query` looks like promising trail with:

`dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package} ${Version}  ${Architecture}  ${Description}\n'`

yet it returns too much information and not so nicely presented as `dpkg -l`:

```
acpi 1.5-2  amd64  displays information on ACPI devices
 Attempts to replicate the functionality of the 'old' apm command on
 ACPI systems, including battery and thermal information. Does not support
 ACPI suspending, only displays information about ACPI devices.
acpi-support-base 0.137-5  all  scripts for handling base ACPI events such as the power button
 This package contains scripts to react to various base ACPI events
 such as the power button. For more extensive ACPI support, including support
 for suspend-to-RAM and for various laptop features, install the package
 "acpi-support".
acpid 1:2.0.7-1squeeze4  amd64  Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take (inferred from the last error message cited) is that you have Wheezy (or Jessie or Sid) on one machine and Squeeze on another.

Debian (and hence its `dpkg` machinery) gained support for the so-called ["multiarch"](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) (an ability to install the same package multiple times—once for an architecture so, say, `i386` and `amd64` builds of the same library might coexist) only in Wheezy.  That could explain the differences you observe.